# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Weekly / Monthly Statistics

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, statistics

I'm new working with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, and I´d like to gather some statistics every week / month for users who are connecting to this server.  For instance, how many times they were connected, which table was most popular or when was the most traffic, etc.

I cannot find anything about this weekly / monthly user statistic for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server doesn't track things like table access and concurrency.

You could do this kind of thing yourself if you do some or all of these things:

- audit logins
- force all data access via stored procedures (and perform custom logging)
- add triggers to capture insert/update/delete activity if you can't force data access through stored procedures
- capture concurrency for activity by taking snapshots of DMVs (e.g. sys.dm_exec_connections, sys.dm_exec_sessions, sys.dm_exec_requests)
- server-side trace / extended events for anything not captured above

Comment: can you please tell us how can we track the Schama changes using `Auditing`? I tried to use `SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP`. My efforts are mentioned in this **[screenshoot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pbDb9.png)**.

Comment: @RGI For DDL changes, I would recommend a DDL trigger instead of auditing. Much simpler to implement and consume. I wrote a tip about this here which covered stored procedures but could easily be extended to other objects: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/ Sorry, but I haven't done anything like this with auditing.